# Управление текстовыми полями из админки Joomla

Tags: wordpress, cms, joomla, реализация

Я верстаю макет сайта по продаже машин, на сайте машины представлены в виде карточек, где описываются их некоторые характеристики. Выглядят эти карточки так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Текстовые данные на этих карточках(кузов, комплектация, двигатель) ни откуда не парсятся, т.е. они вводятся прямо в разметке, например

```html
...
<div class="auto_card">
    <img src="" alt="" class="auto_image">
    <div class="auto_name">Mercedes gle</div>
    <div class="auto_body">Купе</div>
    <div class="auto_equipment">Prestige</div>
    <div class="auto_engine">3.0 л / 380 л.с / бензин</div>
    <div class="auto_price-buy">
        <div class="auto_price">$24,500</div>
        <div class="auto_buy-button"></div>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

И таких блоков на сайте столько же, сколько и машин в макете и все отличаются лишь текстовыми данными. Поэтому в случаях когда надо будет изменить какое то поле придется лезть в `html` и изменять его там. Чтобы избежать такого было решено использовать `CMS Joomla` или `WordPress`(*ну как бы понятно что с ним будет легче*). Но я не знаю как именно можно упростить с помощью `WordPress\Joomla` эту задачу. Я посмотрел курс по этим `cms` и гуглил свой вопрос, но нагуглить так ничего и не удалось. Есть ли способ заполнить\редактировать эти поля в админке чтобы данные с этих полей потом вносились в эти карточки.
Так выглядит полный каталог с карточками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это абстрактный вопрос. На него невозможно дать ответ.

Comment: @IgorR. скоро правлю и уточню

Comment: @IgorR. теперь нормально?